# OCR solution that be able to recognise fields from identity card/passport/driving license

Tags: ocr

I'm looking for an OCR solution (library/service/API) that be able to recognise fields from identity card/passport/driving license. Preferable a paid cloud service.

Edit:
To clarify, I'm looking for any solution (open source or not) that be able to detect: first name, last name, dob etc...

Answer (score 7):

Go for **BlinkID iOS SDK** (https://microblink.com/products/blinkid/mobile-sdk) It is basically providing the best results.
You can also download the demo iOS app available at Appstore and check for various documents.

**Accura Scan** (https://accurascan.com/) is also competitor in the market which provides the accurate results recognising the **MRZ** as well as **PDF417** code format. **Accura Scan** scans the below documents:

1. All countries Passports (with MRZ code)
2. DL of all countries except that if India and Philippines.
3. Alien cards/ID cards

Also, scans QR code/Bar-code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "best results" means and how you have come to that conclusion?

Comment: By "best results", I mean to say that it is actually fetching the details like name, dob, expiry date, country etc. of the user's passport. It is basically coming in clean readable format and you can display/modify the results as per the need.

You can follow the link below for the same iOS SDK in swift: 
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/releases
 
Go for first SDK and it will illustrate you with the whole procedure. 

For more info, you can also follow the below link:
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used any but some cool ones are:

1. Google OCR
2. Tesseract OCR (open source)

Comment: Thanks @Sujil, tried both, both are very good at recognising text. What I'm looking for is for recognising fields like first name, last name, dob etc...

Answer (score 0):

@QuangLihnLe, I just want to clarify, first you need detect passport / id card text with OCR, then validate or parse text as MRZ Text data. MRZ is a standard format for passport / id cards it contains sets of personal data including name, surname, birthday, expiry date etc. I have used MLKit to recognize MRZ data on passport and I made samples.

Android: https://github.com/alimertozdemir/EPassportNFCReader

iOS: https://github.com/alimertozdemir/IDCardPassportNFCReader